# Pivotal: HDFS-HAWQ - Migration to New Hardware

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ambari, hawq

**We have version PHD3.0 hadoop cluster for 5 node using ambari installed on rackspace . We have to migrate into Google cloud (GCP).**

But Not getting steps How to conduct following

**Q1**: How do i migrate data,metadata configuration from Old machine to New machine. ( Old Machine version is cantos 6.5 to target machine version centos 6.5)

**Q2**: What components and folders to backup? What would be the commands?

**Q3**: How to backup nameode and datanodes?

**Q4**: Do we need to take backup of ambari database also?

Any help on it would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally prefer to provision hadoop cluster in GCP and move data using distcp to new cluster. 
For hawq managed tables move data to hdfs and then do distcp.
Some occasions on AWS i moved data to s3 and import back into hadoop.